# How to copy image and paste into product folder using php Magento

Tags: magento2, file

I want to copy a file which is in a folder and copy to pub/media/product folder for product image... my current file directory pub/media/xyz/images/i/j/ijk.jpeg . i want this image to product folder. how to get that using php?

Comment: You can also do copy all folder and file like:cp -r pub/media/xyz/images/* pub/media/catalog/product/  << so that copy your whole folder pub/media/xyz/images/i

Answer (score 0):

use below ssh command to copy file to other folder

```
cp pub/media/xyz/images/i/j/ijk.jpeg pub/media/product
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

```
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

copy($file, $newfile)
```